# One or more lines RegEx Find + Replace in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Search criteria:

Trying to find & replace one or more populated lines with a mixture of static and dynamic texts (there could be empty line(s) or line(s) with just spaces in between the two lines of specific code).

For instance, I want to find every instance of the following 2 populated lines of code and replace it with "--" prepended to both lines

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <dynamic index name> ON <dynamic table name> ( <dynamic list of columns > )
GO
```

or just single line of code (notice there's no subsequent "GO")

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <dynamic index name> ON <dynamic table name> ( <dynamic list of columns > )
```

Example:

The correct regex should find the following

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable1] ON [dbo].[Table1] ( [Id] ASC, [Val] ASC )
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable2] ON [dbo].[Table2] ( [Id1] ASC )
<empty line>
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable3] ON [dbo].[Table3] ( [Value1] ASC )
<empty line>
  <empty line with some spaces>
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable4] ON [dbo].[Table4] ( [Value1] ASC )
```

and replace it with

```
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable1] ON [dbo].[Table1] ( [Id] ASC, [Val] ASC )
--GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable2] ON [dbo].[Table2] ( [Id1] ASC )
<empty line>
--GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable3] ON [dbo].[Table3] ( [Value1] ASC )
--<empty line>
--  <empty line with some spaces>
--GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable4] ON [dbo].[Table4] ( [Value1] ASC )
```

When there is a subsequent "GO", then if there's a way to remove empty lines or empty lines with spaces in between the first and second line, it would be awesome.

NOTE:

I need a regex to ONLY find & replace the "create nonclustered..." and the SUBSEQUENT "GO" if exists. I do NOT want the regex to find & replace everything from "create nonclustered..." to the LAST "GO" in each file.

My attempt

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX .* ON .* ( .* )(.*\n)[GO]
```

Need to exclude 1 or more empty lines or 1 or more empty lines with just spaces in between the two lines, if a subsequent GO exists.

Comment: I noticed that in the `and replace it with` there an `<empty line>` with no `--`, should it also be `--` or no ?

Comment: Yea, if there's a way to remove the in-between empty lines & empty lines with just spaces, it would be great. I made some progress with my attempt so going to update the OP.

Comment: yeah man, it is easier to remove the inline gaps and keep the `CREATE` and `GO` statements. I'm almost done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the regular expression you want to use to *search* is:

```
(CREATE\sNONCLUSTERED\sINDEX\s(.+?)(\sON\s)(.+?))\n\s*(GO)
```

And the regular expression you want to use to *replace* is:

```
--$1\n--$5
```

---

I tried it on the following:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable1] ON [dbo].[Table1] ( [Id] ASC, [Val] ASC )
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable2] ON [dbo].[Table2] ( [Id1] ASC )

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable3] ON [dbo].[Table3] ( [Value1] ASC )



GO
```

And got the following as  a result:

```
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable1] ON [dbo].[Table1] ( [Id] ASC, [Val] ASC )
--GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable2] ON [dbo].[Table2] ( [Id1] ASC )
--GO
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable3] ON [dbo].[Table3] ( [Value1] ASC )
--GO
```

---

Now, the key behind this is that the `.+` is pretty greedy. So if you specify `(.+)STOP` it won't stop at the first `STOP` it sees. It will stop at the last one available. The reason behind it is that, again, it is super greedy.

So doing the following `.+?` will make it less greedy. Therefore, `(.+?)STOP` will make it stop at the first `STOP` it sees.

---

- `CREATE\sNONCLUSTERED\sINDEX\s` : captures what you expect it to *CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX*
- `(.+?)(\sON\s)` : captures the `[Indx_Temp_dboTable] ON`
  We use `ON` in order to indicate when the `Index` ends.
- `(.+?)\n` : captures the rest of the line (until it ends)
- `\s*(GO)` : captures the empty lines (`*` because we might not have any empty lines) until we reach `GO`

---

In the case that you have an optional `GO`, then we need to make the `\s*(GO)` optional. We can do that by just enclosing it in a Capture Group; therefore, `(\s*(GO))`

**However**, now you need to update the replace. The `GO` is captured now by group 6, not 5. So you'll need `--$1\n--$6`.

> Please Note: The `CREATE` line **has** to end with a line break because of the `\n` before capturing the empty lines and the `GO`.

Comment: I tried it on a regex editor website. I'll try it on Sublime just to make sure I don't have any problems with flags such as the `multiline`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the OP. Going to test this code now. Cheers!

Comment: What is "(\s\(.*\)))\s+(GO)" doing?

Comment: I'll add a long explanation of everything, better than commenting it, give me 5 mins please

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the update. I'm still reading this. One thing I want to ask is how do I make the subsequent "GO" optional? I found instances where there is no subsequent "GO" after the CREATE statement. I tried putting [] around "\s+(GO)" but didn't work.

Comment: I'll update the answer again, but can you please tell me, would you have a Line Break to indicate the end of the `CREATE` line or just a `)` ?

Comment: Good question. There are a couple instances of some other characters (such as spaces, or "-- comment" or "/* comment */" and etc after the last ")" shown in example. Can we assume it ends with a line break? Not sure how to see these symbols in VS like we can in NP++

Comment: If it ends with a Line Break, then my updated answer will work just fine :)

Comment: hmm. Tried on regexr and it is unable to find just 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Indx_Temp_dboTable4] ON [dbo].[Table4] ( [Value1] ASC )" (without a "GO" after that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206163/discussion-between-nizar-and-007).

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Cheers! (CREATE\sNONCLUSTERED\sINDEX\s(.+?)(\sON\s)(.+))(\s*(GO))?

Comment: My pleasure :) Thanks for the fun question